# Must the entire class hierarchy be recompiled if a virtual or non-virtual function is added to the base class in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, vtable

I am trying to learn how sensitive the vtable of a class is in C++ and, for that, I need to know whether recompilation of the entire class hierarchy (total, 3 header files) is necessary for the 3 change-scenarios I list below. First, here is my class hierarchy:

```
class A {
   public:
   virtual void method1() = 0;
   virtual void method2() = 0;
   virtual ~A() {} 
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    virtual void method1() {};
    virtual void method2() {};
    virtual ~B() {} 
};

class C : public A {
    public:
    virtual void method1() {};
    virtual void method2() {};
    virtual ~C() {} 
};
```

Here are my scenarios:

1. A non-virtual method is added to the base class A:

   ```
   void method3() {};
   ```
2. A virtual method with a body is added to the base class A:

   ```
   virtual void method3() {};
   ```
3. A purely virtual method is added to the base class A:

   ```
   virtual void method3() = 0;
   ```

In scenario-1, no change to the vtable is made. Is it still required for B and C to be recompiled?

In scenario-2, will the vtable be reconstructed for base A, and consequently for B, and C?

I know scenario-3 will force classes B and C to provide implementations for the new method. So, the entire hierarchy must be recompiled.

Comment: Classes don't get compiled; *files* get compiled. So your question seems underspecified if you don't then tell us what the file structure is.

Comment: Nicol. Good point. I meant to say 3 files, containing those 3 classes, respectively. I have edited my post.

Comment: The ABI is not part of the standard. Each compiler or platform has their own rules. However, KDE is a project that deals with this issue and they maintain a [guidelines page](https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B#The_Do.27s_and_Don.27ts). There's also tools [like this one](https://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) that can help in checking whether a change you made broke the ABI or API.

Comment: Pure virtual function calls are not different to any other virtual function calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ one-definition-rule makes it clear that definitions of entities in different translation units (ie: files) *must* all be identical if you're going to link them together. As such, if you change the definition of a class at all, public, private, `virtual`, non-`virtual`, *whatever*, all translation units that use that definition have to be looking at the new class definition. And that will require recompiling it.

Failure to do this is il-formed, but no diagnostic (linker-error) is required. So your project may appear to link just fine. Indeed, it may actually work in some cases. But there's nothing which guarantees in which cases they will work and in which cases they will not.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Yes, I see the translation units are changing in each scenario!

Comment: "Failure to do this is il-formed, but no diagnostic (linker-error) is required." That tells us how we should take precautions in general. But, Nicol, I still would like to know if recompilation is mandatory for virtual cases. Isn't the vtable destroyed if any modification is made by adding a virtual function? Doesn't that force recompilation of the entire hierarchy?

Comment: @softwarelover: "*I still would like to know if recompilation is mandatory for virtual cases*" That would be implementation-dependent and potentially subject to change at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless the missing `virtual`destructor of `A` you have an *interface* here:

```
class A {
   public:
   virtual void method1() = 0;
   virtual void method2() = 0;
   virtual ~A() {} // This is needed
};
```

An *interface* is a contract that shouldn't be broken.

If you want to extend interfaces without the need to recompile the complete codebase, you can use inheritance and dynamic polymorphism checks:

```
class AEx : public A {
public:
   virtual void method3() = 0;
   virtual ~AEx() {}
};
```

In functions which handle the extensions you can do

```
void foo(A* pA) {
    AEx pAEx = dynamic_cast<AEx*>(pa);
    if(pAEx) {
       pAEx->method3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the virtual destructors. You mentioned about designing a hierarchy but my design is already given. I just need to know the impact of adding something (3 scenarios) to the base class B.

Comment: @softwarelover So as mentioned you have to recompile your complete code base.