# C++: pure virtual functions and binary compatibility

Tags: c++, dll, virtual-functions, abi, vtable

I've written a Windows C++ DLL (MSVS2017) that can be loaded by 3rd party applications.

My DLL contains a function which can return a pointer to an interface of a custom class containing pure virtual functions which I implement. The header file defining this class has been provided to 3rd party developers, so they can cast pointers of my classes to the interface class and call the functions.

So the interface I provide to other developers looks like this:

```
class MyInterface
{
   virtual int foo() = 0;
};
```

And my class looks like this:

```
class MyClass : public MyInterface
{
    int foo(){return 1;}
};
```

Once a 3rd party app has loaded my DLL and received a pointer to a MyClass object they can do this:

```
#include "MyInterface.h"
...
MyInterface* interface = (MyInterface*)pointerSentFromMyDLL;
int result = interface->foo();
```

However, what if I want to modify the MyInterface.h header file and add some new functions. Is that possible without breaking their applications? Or do they also need to recompile with the updated header?

For example, if I modify my header like this:

```
class MyInterface
{
   virtual float bar() = 0;
   virtual int foo() = 0;
};
```

And then implement the new function in my DLL and recompile it, will their usage of the old header still work in their compiled code? Or do they need to recompile with the modified header? Obviously they wouldn't be able to call bar(), but could they still call foo() without recompiling?

In other words, do we all need to recompile if pure virtual functions are added to the interface class, or just me?

Comment: Is your Q different from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56431823/963864)?

Comment: If you only add functions (at the end), and don't change any you already made public before, it should be fine.